# Javascript Sort() Array In Numeric Order

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have array like this

```
var Arr = [ 'h78em', 'w145px', 'w13px' ]
```

I want to sort this array in Numerical Order

```
[ 'w13px', 'h78em', 'w145px' ]
```

For Regular Numerical sorting I use this function

```
var sortArr = Arr.sort(function(a,b){
     return a-b;
});
```

But due to word character in the array this function doesn't work

Is it possible to sort this array ? How do I split/match array ?

Comment: "78em", "145px" : those are different units. Why this sort ? Do you want it independently of the unit or should em to pixel conversion occurs ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use regular expression to remove all letters when sorting:

```
var Arr = [ 'h78em', 'w145px', 'w13px' ]​;
var sortArr = Arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    a = a.replace(/[a-z]/g, "");  // or use .replace(/\D/g, "");
    b = b.replace(/[a-z]/g, "");  // to leave the digits only
    return a - b;
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/8RNKE/

Comment: I would add `i` so it doesn't only check for lowercase, making it safer.

Comment: @sQVe Good catch. There is also an option to leave only digits using `/[\D]/g`. However, it depends on the input.